# Removing unused python versions macos Catalina

Tags: python, homebrew, macos-catalina

Over the years, exploring different configurations in my macbook I have ended up with multiple Python installations. My goal is to eliminate versions that are doing nothing or are repeated.

```
 which -a python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.6 python3.7 python3.8
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

These are my python versions. Which of these versions can I remove. I think the ones I double installed on homebrew but I'm not sure which ones and I don't want to remove the ones that are original on my system.

Once I decide which versions I want to remove, is there a recommended method to do it?

Edit 1:
@MarkSetchell brew search python output is:

```
app-engine-python             boost-python3                 ipython                       python ✔                      python-yq                     wxpython
boost-python                  gst-python                    micropython                   python-markdown               python@3.8 ✔
```

But I think that I have some of them repeated:

```
/usr/local/bin/python 
/usr/local/bin/python 
/usr/local/bin/python3 
/usr/local/bin/python3 
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

Do I need to `rm` them mannually?

Edit 2:

This is my `.bash_profile` configuration:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: Never remove or change anything in `/usr/bin`. That is provided by and relied upon by your OS vendor/supplier. Run `brew search python` and it will highlight all the Pythons it has installed and you can safely remove any of them that are upsetting you with `brew rm XXX`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `brew search python` output is
app-engine-python             boost-python3                 ipython                       python ✔                      python-yq                     wxpython
boost-python                  gst-python                    micropython                   python-markdown               python@3.8 ✔

But I think that I have some of them repeated:
``
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
``
do I need to ``rm`` them mannually?

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and paste and format all the new info in there. It's too hard to read in comments.

Comment: @MarkSetchell done. Thanks!

Comment: The duplicated lines that start with `/usr/local/bin` mean this path is duplicated in your `PATH` environment variable. Both `/usr/local/bin/python` are a single file but it’s checked twice by the `which` command.

Comment: @bfontaine I'm going to edit the original question so you can see the configuration of my `.bash_profile'. If you can help me to correct it to avoid repetitions I will be very grateful because it is a problem that I have been having for quite some time.

Comment: @StevenGonzález see at the beginning, `/usr/local/bin` appears twice: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:…`. You should remove one instance: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:…`.